# I need help with mechanical rig

Tags: rigging

I want bone.004 and bone.002 to always stay straight (edit: I don't want any bend between)
already tried track to constraint
[image: not straight]

[image: straight][image]

[final rig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okJJ2.jpg)

Comment: Give bone.004 a copy rotation constraint targeting bone.002, world space->world space.  (Check the bone axes of each to make sure they exist in the exact same orientation.)

Comment: not working @Nathan